# entityFields="*" returns record ={}

Tags: canvas, sfrestrequest

Using signed request to run canvas app through a vf page.

If `entityFields=" * "` is specified for the contact vf page, then the returned record is coming as empty.

It works perfectly fine for all the different orgs, and other objects such as Account and Lead.

But in case of Contact, only for this org, I am getting `record={}` if `entityFields="*"` in the vf page. Now if I change the vf page to `entityFields="Id,Email"` etc. then it works, it returns `record={Id='',Email='',attributes={}}`.

I am a system admin, and have permissions for all the fields.

Comment: We seeing a similar issue but only for existing Account records. For new records, it works fine. The other object (Opportunity) that our canvas app is on works correctly for both existing and new records. We are using the canvas app component in our page layout and not a vf page. We also are looking at this as a System admin with permission for all fields.

Comment: I could only get this to work after I changed the entityFields to specific fields. I am still not sure why this issue occured, but was able to get it work by the way I specified.

Comment: I opened up a case with Salesforce regarding this recently. I will update with what they say. they are currently "investigating"